# Javascript - Undefined Array of input field values on Enter click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have the following text input:

```
<input class="form-control" id="ar-array" type="text" name="ar-array" value="" placeholder="Type a keyword and hit return to add items to the array">
```

And my JavaScript code is the following:

```
var rowsArr = new Array();
  $("#ar-array").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var item = $("ar-array").val();
      rowsArr.push(item);
      console.log(rowsArr);
    }
});
```

So, when I hit enter in my keyboard, my js code is supposed to add the value of my `ar-array` input field in the `rowsArr`, and it actually does that, but the value is `undefined`, here's my console log:

```
(2) [undefined, undefined]
0: undefined
1: undefined
length: 2
```

I get that result by typing something like `keyword1` and hitting Enter, then I type `keyword2` and hit Enter again.
What am I doing wrong in my js code? Why can't I print the `keyword1`and `keyword2` values in my console?

Comment: It's a typographical error, should be `var item = $("#ar-array").val();`

Comment: `var item = $("ar-array").val();` change to `var item = $("#ar-array").val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update

```
var rowsArr = new Array();
 var item = $("ar-array").val();
```

with

```
 var rowsArr = [];
 var item = $("#ar-array").val();
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

You have missed `#` in the selector. Though I will suggest you to use `this` to refer the current element to which the *event* is bound:

```js
var rowsArr = new Array();
$("#ar-array").on('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var item = $(this).val();
    rowsArr.push(item);
    console.log(rowsArr);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="ar-array" type="text" name="ar-array" value="" placeholder="Type a keyword and hit return to add items to the array">
```

Answer (score 1):

**var item = $("ar-array").val();** replace with **var item = $("#ar-array").val();** 
because you get the value by using id and when we use,

id then use #
class then use .
tag then tagname